# MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes() returns empty string

Tags: vb.net, miniprofiler

I'm working on ASP.NET WebForms application and trying to implement MiniProfiler.
I have latest version from NuGet (4.0.138) and I implemented all neccessary steps in Global.asax and web.config.

Global.asax:

```
Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MiniProfiler.Configure(New MiniProfilerOptions With {
        .RouteBasePath = "~/mini-profiler-resources",
        .StackMaxLength = 256,
        .TrackConnectionOpenClose = True
    })
End Sub

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MiniProfiler.StartNew()
End Sub

Sub Application_EndRequest()
    MiniProfiler.Current?.Stop()
End Sub
```

Web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Default.aspx (somewhere at the bottom):

```
<%=MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes()  %>
<%=MiniProfiler.Current.Render()  %>
```

The problem is that MiniProfiler.Current.RenderIncludes() always returns an empty string while MiniProfiler.Current.Render() actually returns some data.

I need RenderIncludes() beacuse it should generate JS code that shows results nice formatted.

[image]